# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 disappears after a Windows Restart

Tags: c#, sql

I know this is one of the most popular questions on SO: The Famous "SQL error 26" the difference is that my C# application establishes a connection successfully the first time and then refuses to establish a connection the second time. I restart my computer and the application establishes a connection the first time and then requires a restart again.

The fact that I can establish a connection the first time makes me feel confident that: My server name is correct, My instance name is correct, the username and password combination I use are correct, the server machine is on, the SQL Browser service on the server is running, and I can get through the firewall.

I have a bunch of methods that all look very similar to the following:

```
private static string connection_string = @"Server=my_server\MS_SQL;User Id=user1;Password=password1"

public static List<string> GetListOfExistingItems(int item_id)
    {
        List<string> list_items = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql_conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
            {
                sql_conn.Open();

                SqlCommand sql_comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM dbo.table1 WHERE ID=" + item_id, 
                                                     sql_conn);

                using (SqlDataReader sql_reader = sql_comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sql_reader.Read())
                    {
                        list_items.Add(sql_reader["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                    sql_reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
            throw new Exception(excp.Message);
        }
        return list_items;
    }
```

A few interesting facts:

- A restart fixes the problem (once).
- A log out and log in does NOT fix the problem.
- If I do not close the application but instead run the query multiple times, the error does not show up.
- I cannot connect to my database from SQL Server Management Studio after I run my application and close it once.
- When I restart my computer I see the "Waiting for background programs to close" without any programs being listed. I wait for some time (maybe 10-20 seconds) and the message goes away and the computer eventually restarts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems obvious that the DB Server is refusing subsequent connections by the same user or computer or IP or MAC. First, make sure you are closing connecctions when you are done with them, then check in the server configuration to find the governor.

Comment: Is your application creating subsequent connections to one that is already opened?  Or are your applications querying the database in a manner that is depleting the server resources?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens every single connection I open is unique and is nested in its own using block as shown above. Would you please elaborate on "check the server configuration to find the governor"?

Comment: @Greg All my connections follow the same format as above: the using bock for the connection and a separate  using block for the DataReader. How can I check to see if I am depleting the server's resources. But I do not think that restarting my computer would free up these resources. Would it?

Comment: Well, an example would be a virtual index that the server populates at the time of startup and usage.  So it starts at I believe 4GB of disk space to store so it can handle these request- but that is an example without you knowing the server is already utilizing resources.  When you reboot, the extra store it acquired. Will then go back to its default 4GB size.  So yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you're not closing your connection.

My next troubleshooting step would be to string-search your code (all of it) for `sql_conn.Open();`, and find the one(s) not in a using block, or otherwise not getting explicitly closed.

Comment: Not only have I searched for 'sql_conn.Open();' I have also searched for 'Open();' with no luck